# How to highlight text automatically inside an UIAlertView text field

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview, highlighting

I have an UIAlertView with a textfield that shows a default value and two buttons, one to cancel and the other one to confirm. What I am trying to do is that when the alert view is popped up the default value is highlighted so the user can overwrite the whole value faster than manually erasing it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil];
[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"87893" label:@"value"];
UITextField *textField = [alert textField];
campoTexto.highlighted = YES;
campoTexto.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

For some reason there is a highlighted attribute for the textfield but it doesn't seem to work and there is no trail of that attribute in the Class documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation.  I wanted to prompt the user for a new value, however, I didn't want the original value to disappear, but I also didn't want the text appending to the value.

I ended up calling

```
[alertView show];
[textField selectAll:self];
```

One thing you might also look out for is you are setting keyboardType and highlighted on `campoTexto` which is not the text field you're getting from the alert view.